# Deleting memory pointed to by a void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, delete-operator, void-pointers

I'm creating a new `struct SThreadInfo` in a function:

```
struct SThreadInfo {
    int             function;
    Exchange*       pThis;
};

struct SThreadInfo *threadInfo = new (struct SThreadInfo);
    threadInfo->function    = 0;
    threadInfo->pThis       = this;
```

Then, in the same function, I create a new thread an pass the struct as void-pointer:

```
pthread_t ret;
pthread_create(&ret, NULL, Exchange::staticThreadHelper, (void*)threadInfo);
```

In the new thread, I rebuild the struct from the void-pointer:

```
void* Exchange::staticThreadHelper(void* t)
{
    struct SThreadInfo* threadInfo = (struct SThreadInfo*)t;
    //....
    //....
}
```

At the end of this function I want to delete the memory allocated by `t` and `threadInfo`. By now, it works for `threadInfo` but not for `t`

```
delete threadInfo;
delete static_cast<struct SThreadInfo*>(t);
```

When I try to cast the void-pointer back to SThreadInfo, a SIGABRT is raised. 
Can someone tell me how to delete the memory from the void-pointer properly?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Really? Surely the compiler should complain at the point of compilation in that case. Is the problem not that of "double delete", in other words that the OP is trying to delete the same object twice?

Comment: Have a look at the last piece of code - I'm trying to use static_cast

Comment: It looks like you are deleting the memory twice: once through t and once through threadInfo.  Since threadInfo is just a cast of t, both point to the same object, which can only be deleted once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line:

```
struct SThreadInfo* threadInfo = (struct SThreadInfo*)t;
```

doesn't "***rebuild***" anything, it merely assigns a type casted value to the declared variable. It's the same pointer.

In the end of the function, you appear to be deleting (freeing) the same address twice, and that's why you get your exception.

Comment: Thank you! Actually pretty obvious :D

Answer (score 2):

So, the problem here is that you have ONE lump of memory, that you have two different pointers to.

You should only free any allocated memory ONCE. If you have an object with a destructor [including ones that have implict destruction, e.g. something containing another object with a destructor, such as `std::string` or `std::vector`], you should make sure the `delete` call is made with the correct type.

So in this case, either `delete static_cast<SthreadInfo*>(t);` or `delete threadinfo;` should do the trick. Trying to `delete` the same memory more than once will lead to undefined behaviour [apparently your runtime library detects this and aborts the execution].

Comment: `delete threadInfo;` will also work, since `threadInfo` is typed as `struct SThreadInfo*` and so will call the same destructor as `delete static_cast<SthreadInfo*>(t);`.  Just don't call both `delete` statements, since they are two pointers to the same memory block, which should only be freed once.